# Custom table header section

Tags: ios, uitableview

I got an app with group style table.

I tried to customize table header section:

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 30)];
    UILabel *userName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake (0,0,200,30)];
    if (section != 0)userName.text = @"lalala";
    [userName setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:20]];
    [headerView addSubview:userName];
    [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [userName setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    return headerView;
}
```

But my headers close cells:

[image]

Why?

Comment: FYI, you can use story board to drag out a UIView and place it as a table header. Then assign it to an IBOutlet.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You also need to implement `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` to set the correct height for the section header. See [the Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006942-CH3-SW3)

Answer (score 5):

This is happening because the height of your header is set to 0 until you override the other delegate:

– tableView:heightForHeaderInSection: